# Measuring clock frequency on pin on MSP430

Tags: c, msp430

Using embedded programming.

working on msp430F6779 and need to check frequency of DCO(if is 25MHz).

Idea was to pull frequency on I/O pin and measure frequency with oscilloscope.

In the datasheet there is nothing written about this opportunity.

The question is how to get frequency on pin?

Config of DCO

```
// FLL reference
 UCSCTL3 |= SELREF_2;       // REFO - 32 kHz

// initialize DCO - 25 MHz
__bis_SR_register(SCG0);    // Disable the FLL loop control
UCSCTL0 |= 0x0000;          // select lowest one
UCSCTL1 = DCORSEL_5;        // range suitable for 25 MHz operation, see datasheet MSP430F677x page 68
UCSCTL2 = FLLD_1 + 762;     // Set DCO Multiplier for 25 MHz
                            // (N + 1) * FLLRef = Fdco
                            // (761 + 1) * 32768 = 25MHz
                            // Set FLL Div = fDCOCLK/1
 __bic_SR_register(SCG0);   // Enable the FLL control loop
```

Comment: You would be better off asking such questions on the TI forums at e2e.ti.com as the people there are very knowledgeable about the MSP430 and the information within the relevant datasheets

Answer (score 1):

You can output clock *signals* (ACLK, MCLK, SMCLK) on a pin.

The DCO is a clock *source*.

Configure some clock signal to be sourced from the DCO (with the SELA/SELS/SELM fields in UCSCTL4), and output that.

Comment: By configuring the appropriate pin.